# How to use custom view to update user via devise? (rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have 2 custom views I built for devise, 1 changes the password the other updates other custom information. The password update worked, so I copied the method for the second view, however I am getting an error when **submitting** the data

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/users/discovery_settings/update"
```

which does not make sense because my route is

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}
 as :user do 

end    
get 'users/discovery_settings' => 'users#discovery_settings'
post 'users/discovery_settings/update' => 'users#update_discovery'
```

in my controller i user the same method that works for password updates

```
  def update_discovery
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
     if @user.update(user_params)
       # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
       sign_in @user, :bypass => true
       redirect_to root_path
     else
       render "edit"
     end
  end
```

then i call it in my form_for view

```
 <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_discovery" }, html: {class: "form floating-label"})  do |f| %>
```

Any ideas how to fix the routing error? 
I am at a lost as to why it is looking for "patch" when i have already specified "post"

Comment: where my devise ninja masters at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's telling you. You have a POST route and the update is asking for a PATCH route.

try with **patch** instead of **post**:

```
patch 'users/discovery_settings/update' => 'users#update_discovery'
```